# blocking ip on linux(CENTOS)

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, ip

I m blocking an ip from my centos server using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j DROP
service iptables save
```

however my ip is still able to access the ip and even view websites hosted on this ip.
what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to block the outgoing traffic to this ip address not the other-way around.

Use the `OUTPUT` keyword and the `-d` flag like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ip -j DROP
```

Comment: You'll also need to use the `-d` flag to specify the IP as destination, not source.  And of course you may run afoul of the fact that order is important in `iptables` rules, and slapping one on the end of a chain doesn't guarantee it'll ever do anything at all.